# How to show a last modified LocalDateTime in Java 8?

Tags: java, javafx-8, last-modified, localdate

I am developing a basic contact address application using *Java FX*.
I am using `LocalDateTime` and I have also created a class to format the date and time into a String so I can display it in *Label* of *Java FX*.
However, I do not understand how can I display the date and time when I create a new contact or when I edit one that already exists (I have already implemented all the functions I have just described, except the one I am asking right now).
At the moment I have managed only to enter manually a date and a time via GUI, but that is not what I want.

If you need any other relevant information or some snippets of the code to help me faster, just ask and I will edit the post.

Comment: Are you looking for [`LocalDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--)??? (For timestamps `Instant` is preferable though.) If that does not answer your question I've no idea why saving the modification time when editing the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, just generate a date in your method that creates or edit the contact.

```
String currentDate = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

You can also use timezones.

```
String currentDate = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Read about java date here: http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Comment: I have a model class with different attributes, one of those is `ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> creationTime;`. In this class also I have a default constructor and a constructor with some initial data just for testing. I got also getters and setters for all my attributes and also this methot `public ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> creationTimeProperty() {
        return creationTime;
    }`. I still do not get If I have to edit the model or not, because the controller class of the edit/new dialog calls these methods here. Thanks, hope that is clear

Comment: I think I got it anyway. Thanks

Comment: This represent most likely a List of LocalDates which I assume would be all the edits.